# Working with javascript in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a javascript object which is built dynamically and contains my resources (strings of translation) for my app. It looks as follows:

```
var ResourceManager = (function () {
    function ResourceManager() {
        var currentLanguage = $('#activeLanguage').html();
        this.resources = {
            get Aanmelden() {
                switch (currentLanguage) {
                case "en-GB":
                    return "Register";
                case "nl-NL":
                    return "Aanmelden";
                default:
                    return "Aanmelden";
                }
            },
            get AlgemeenOpslaan() {
                switch (currentLanguage) {
                    case "en-GB":
                        return "Save";
                    case "nl-NL":
                        return "Opslaan";
                    default:
                        return "Opslaan";
                }
            }
        };

    }
    return ResourceManager;
}());
```

The neat thing is that this way I can use intellisense to find my translations, just like the functionality provided by MVC. Is there a way to provide the same functionality when I am working in typescript? The main problem here is that I could do:

```
declare class ResourceManager {

}
```

This however does not give me intellisense for the methods of this class. The reason I use javascript and not typescript btw, is because if I dynamically build a typescript file, it does not seem to automatically compile this to the javascript file I want to send to the client.

Does anyone know either a way to  fix this via a typescript resource file instead of javascript, or allowing my other typescript files to work with intellisense over the javascript object?

Answer (score 1):

## The code in TypeScript

I'm unsure what is the need. Maybe this kind of code?

```
class ResourceManager {
    private currentLanguage: string;
    constructor() {
        this.currentLanguage = $('#activeLanguage').html();
    }
    public resources = {
        get Aanmelden() {
            switch (this.currentLanguage) {
                case "en-GB":
                    return "Register";
                case "nl-NL":
                default:
                    return "Aanmelden";
            }
        },
        get AlgemeenOpslaan() {
            switch (this.currentLanguage) {
                case "en-GB":
                    return "Save";
                case "nl-NL":
                default:
                    return "Opslaan";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice: You can [call the TypeScript compiler programmatically](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#a-simple-transform-function).

## Or a declaration for an existing object

```
interface Resources {
    readonly Aanmelden: string
    readonly AlgemeenOpslaan: string
}

declare class ResourceManager {
    resources: Resources
}
```

It is also an elegant solution to output the declaration and the data (the code) in separate files. You could:

1. Generate the TypeScript definition for the interface `Resources`;
2. Generate data in a JSON format;
3. Write once a JS code (with the help of TS?) that dynamically builds the `resources` properties with [Object.defineProperties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties), from the JSON data.

Additionally, this kind of build process could help to publish and use the work as a npm package.

Comment: That does indeed give me the intellisense, but now each time a new resource gets added I need to add a property to the interface as well. It sounds stupid but I COULD build a ts file AND a js file. Use the ts one just for intellisense and the js file to send to the client I guess.

Note that the issue is that I can't seem to programmatically build a typescript file and then compile it so it is included as js in my request.

Comment: @Kai NB: You can [call the TypeScript compiler programmatically](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#a-simple-transform-function). I edited to add the link in the answer.